# How to create query to find there is a team does not won

Tags: mysql, sql

I need create a query to find out if there is a team that has not won a game yet. My result set should include ALL of the teams regardless of whether there is a match in game. In my output I should include the team id, team name, game id and game date. How can I do this. I tried different ways but everything were wrong. Thanks.
This is my Team table:

```
CREATE TABLE team(
teamID          integer,
teamName        char(15)
--constraints
CONSTRAINT teamID_pk primary key(teamID)
);

INSERT INTO team
    (teamID,teamName)
    VALUES
    (101, 'Purple Pilots'),
    (102, 'Red Devils'),
    (103, 'Silver Lions'),
    (104, 'Blue Jackets'),
    (105, 'Green Hornets'),
    (106, 'Gold Dragons'),
    (100, 'No Winner')
;
```

This is my game table:

```
CREATE TABLE game(
gameID          integer,
gameDate        DATE,  
gameTime        TIME,
home_team       integer     not null,
visitor_team    integer     not null, 
winning_team    integer     not null default 100, 
refID           integer     not null,
locationID      integer     not null, 
score           char(10),

constraint gameID_pk primary key(gameID),
CONSTRAINT hometeam_fk foreign key(home_team) REFERENCES team(teamID),
constraint visitorteam_fk foreign key(visitor_team) references team(teamID),
CoNSTRAINT winningteam_fk foreign key(winning_team) REFERENCES team(teamID),
CONSTRAINT refID_fk foreign key(refID) REFERENCES person(personID),
CONSTRAINT locationID_fk foreign key(locationID) references location(locationID)
);

INSERT INTO game
     (gameID, gameDate, gameTime, home_team, visitor_team, winning_team, refID, locationID, score)
    VALUES
     (10012, '8/23/2012', '6:00 PM', 101, 105, 105, 160, 2, '21 - 10'), 
     (10013, '8/23/2012', '6:00 PM', 102, 106, 102, 161, 1, '14 - 0'),
     (10014, '8/23/2012', '6:00 PM', 104 ,103, 104, 162, 3, '24 - 3'),
     (10015, '8/30/2012', '6:00 PM', 105, 102, 105, 161, 1, '17 - 14'),
     (10000, '8/30/2012', '6:00 PM', 106, 104, 106, 162, 2, '14 - 3'), 
     (10001, '8/30/2012', '6:00 PM', 103, 101, 103, 161, 3, '10 - 7'), 
     (10002, '9/6/2012', '6:00 PM', 102, 106, 102, 162, 2, '27 - 14'),
     (10003, '9/6/2012', '6:00 PM', 104, 103, 104, 161, 3, '14 - 7'),
     (10004, '9/6/2012', '6:00 PM', 101, 105, 101, 160, 1, '27 - 7'), 
     (10005, '9/13/2012', '6:00 PM', 106, 104, 106, 162, 1, '14 - 7'), 
     (10006, '9/13/2012', '6:00 PM', 103, 101, 103, 160, 2, '21 - 7'),
     (10007, '9/13/2012', '6:00 PM', 105, 102, 105, 161, 3, '21 - 20')
;
```

And that what I tried to do with this task:

```
select teamID, teamName, gameID, gameDate, winning_team
from team t join game g
     on t.teamID != g.winning_team
intersect
select teamID, teamName, gameID, gameDate, winning_team
from team t join game g
     on t.teamID != g.winning_team
where teamID >= 100
order by gameID  


teamID teamName gameID gameDate 
----------- --------------- ----------- ---------- 
 100 No Winner NULL NULL 
 106 Gold Dragons 10000 2012-08-30 
 103 Silver Lions 10001 2012-08-30 
 102 Red Devils 10002 2012-09-06 
 104 Blue Jackets 10003 2012-09-06 
 101 Purple Pilots 10004 2012-09-06 
 106 Gold Dragons 10005 2012-09-13 
 103 Silver Lions 10006 2012-09-13 
 105 Green Hornets 10007 2012-09-13 
 105 Green Hornets 10012 2012-08-23 
 102 Red Devils 10013 2012-08-23 
 104 Blue Jackets 10014 2012-08-23 
 105 Green Hornets 10015 2012-08-30
```

Comment: Could you please include the expected output based on the given data?

Comment: Minor suggestion, since I've designed something similar for a soccer club.  Break the score into two columns   You mind need to compute standings and often point differential or points scored are tiebreakers in standings.   Also, do your system allow ties?

Answer (score 0):

The following query will probably work for your requirement. It selects teams which have not won any games yet. For these teams, all games are listed.

```
select t.teamID, t.teamName, g.gameID, g.gameDate, g.winning_team
from team t left outer join
(select distinct winning_team from game) winners
on t.teamID = winners.winning_team
left outer join game g
on t.teamID = g.home_team or t.teamID = g.visitor_team
where winners.winning_team is null
```

Here's the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9c490/2).

Comment: Thank you. You give me idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to show standings

```
select t.teamName,count(g.gameId) as TotalWins
from team t
left join game g on t.teamId = g.winning_team
group by g.winning_team,t.teamName
having count(g.gameId) = 0            -- This line shows teams with no wins only
order by 2 desc
```

To show game details (with null game values if team never played)

```
select distinct xx.teamId,xx.TeamName,xx.totalWins,g.gameId,g.gameDate,g.score
from (
    select t.teamId,t.teamName,count(g.gameId) as TotalWins
    from team t
        left join game g on t.teamId = g.winning_team
        group by g.winning_team,t.teamName
    ) xx  
 left join game g on xx.teamid=g.home_team or xx.teamid=g.visitor_team
 order by TotalWins desc,teamId,gameId
```